# Regularity of biharmonic problem with solution $u \in H_0^2(\Omega)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde

Supose $f \in L^2(\Omega)$, $\Omega$ bounded and  $u \in H_0^2(\Omega)$ weak solution for biharmonic problem
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\Delta^2u=f\\
u=\partial_{\nu} u=0 \ \mbox{in} \ \partial \Omega
\end{array}\right.
$$
Can I prove that $u \in H^4(\Omega)$? I am trying use the theorems of regularity elliptc of Evans but I can't solve this.

Comment: did you get anything on it. Actually I am also looking into the same direction. Although I am working with the non linear equation together with the obstacle and I am looking to get a fine estimate on $\lVert u\rVert^2_{H^3(\Omega)}$ and $\lVert \Delta^2u\rVert^2_{L^2(\Omega)}$. In case you have something on it please share. It would be very helpful.

Comment: @bunny i don't remember, but i think so i looked a pdf of Marcelo Cavalcanti - Semigrupo de Operadores, page 180. It is a similar problem no Neumann condition.